# Connect a recurring callback to a promise chain

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

The childAdded callback inside the method is called, well, every time a child is added (aka multiple times):

```
        listenToBuildRequests({
            childAdded: (value, key) => {
                console.log('value, key -> ', value, key);
            }
        });
```

Is there away, with ES6 or a 3rd party, to connect it to a promise chain?

```
 childAdded()
    .then(...
```

I know it's not standard and I know promises run one time through and this will require the generation of a new promise every time. However working with Firebase and promises it will save me the need of repeatedly starting a promise chain inside a callback:

```
listenToBuildRequests({
            childAdded: (value, key) => {
                createBuildDirectory(appId).
                       then(...
            }
        });
```

A very simple JSBin example (without chaining) which is not assuming to replicate the promise pattern but rather play with the concept:
http://jsbin.com/mekoza/edit?js,console

Comment: `createBuildDirectory` needs to return a promise that fulflls (or rejects) after its asynchronous operation  finishes. The `then(...` you've coded (once) still works because its called on the returned promise

Comment: No, putting the promise chain inside the listener is exactly the right thing to do. What would a promise outside of `listToBuildRequests` represent?

Answer (score 1):

A promise can only resolve once. Since `on()` can fire multiple times, it cannot be chained into a promise chain.

If you only care about the first child that is added, you can use `once()`. This fires only once and *does* return a promise.

Comment: I have a feeling it can be technically done. A promise is in a way a holder of callbacks. Is there a reason why those callbacks can't be remembered and re-fired with different variables?

Comment: For instance, a simplified POC: http://jsbin.com/mekoza/edit?js,console

Comment: It technically is very feasible to call a method each time a child is added. But it wouldn't be a promise anymore.

Comment: @Guy Because when you re-fire them, you've violated the Promise contract. What you got then is a Stream not a Promise any more.

Comment: I guess I want it all in a way. The benefits of promises with the ability to re-use the chain.

Comment: Promises are a very specific contract and `on()` does not fit with that contract. Closest to what you want is RX's `onNext()`.

Answer (score 0):

> The childAdded callback inside the method is called, well, every time
>   a child is added (aka multiple times). Is there away, with ES6 or a
>   3rd party, to connect it to a promise chain?

You can do this:

```
(function () {

    // do some stuff

    return Promise.resolve("pass this value on to .then")
})()

.then ()
.then ()
.then ();
```

but as stated in clause 25.4 of the [ECMAScript 2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> A promise is said to be settled if it is not pending, i.e. if it is
>   either fulfilled or rejected.
>
> A promise is resolved if it is settled or if it has been “locked in”
>   to match the state of another promise. Attempting to resolve or reject
>   a resolved promise has no effect.

and therefore you cannot reject or resolve a `Promise` once it has been settled. So there is no way around creating new `Promise`'s for each run through of a `Promise` chain.